# Ant command line arguments

Tags: java, ant

Program works fine when run with eclipse run configurations, but when run with ant, it is unable to parse int from args[0], which I do not understand. Full code is available here https://gist.github.com/4108950/e984a581d5e9de889eaf0c8faf0e57752e825a97
I believe it has something to do with ant,

```
target name="run" description="run the project">
   java dir="${build.dir}" classname="BinarySearchTree" fork="yes">
    <arg value="6 in.txt"/>
   /java>
/target>
```

the arg value will be changed via the -D flag, as in ant -Dargs="6 testData1.txt" run.

Any help would be much appreciated, it is very frustrating.

Answer (score 7):

You need to supply the arguments as two different `arg` values:

```
<target name="run" description="run the project">
   <java dir="${build.dir}" classname="BinarySearchTree" fork="yes">
       <arg value="6" />
       <arg value="in.txt" />
   </java>
</target>
```

---

You can also use the `line` attribute; From the `ANT` docs:

```
<arg value="-l -a"/>
```

> is a single command-line argument containing a space character, not separate commands "-> l" and "-a".

```
<arg line="-l -a"/>
```

> This is a command line with two separate arguments, "-l" and "-a".

Comment: Thank you. How can I configure it to be changed by the -D flag, for running with multiple commands, such as -Dargs="6 test1.txt" and then -Dargs="4 test.txt"? Thanks.

Comment: Still receiving the following error when trying to specify -D
    run:
     [java] Exception in thread "main"     java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-Ddefault.debug=10"
     [java]  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
     [java]  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
     [java]  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:514)
     [java]  at BinarySearchTree.main(Unknown Source)
     [java] Java Result: 1

Answer (score 1):

Expanding epoch 's answer.

[java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html)  supports sysproperty and jvmarg.

For example (from ant java task page)

> ```
> <java classname="test.Main"
>     fork="yes" >
> <sysproperty key="DEBUG" value="true"/>
> <arg value="-h"/>
> <jvmarg value="-Xrunhprof:cpu=samples,file=log.txt,depth=3"/>   </java>
> ```

So you could construct the args from the command line passed to ant.

```
<target name="run" description="run the project">
   <java dir="${build.dir}" classname="BinarySearchTree" fork="yes">

      <sysproperty key="testarg"  value="${testarg}"
       <arg value="${arg1}" />
       <arg value="${arg2}" />

   </java>
</target>
```

Now if you call ant with `ant -Dtestarg=test1234 -Darg1=6 -Darg2=in.txt`, then `testarg` will be available via property. Others will become normal arguments to the java program.